# Why is TypeError raised when attribute name matches class name using typing?

Tags: python, typing

I'm unable to initialise a dataclass list attribute where the attribute has the same name as the list elements' class.

The initialisation works fine when the attribute name is changed. I have the same problem with Pydantic classes.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List

@dataclass
class Thing:
    name: str

@dataclass
class MyClass:
    Thing: List[Thing] = field(default_factory=list)

c = MyClass()
```

This gives the following error:

```py
TypeError: Parameters to generic types must be types. Got Field(name=None,type=None,default=<dataclasses._MISSING_TYPE object at 0x00000201CA208518>,default_f.
```

When I change:

```py
    Thing: List[Thing] = field(default_factory=list)
```

to:

```py
    thing: List[Thing] = field(default_factory=list)
```

the TypeError is not raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because then it's overriding `Thing`.

That's why `thing` works.

Comment: Yes, type hint seems to be evaluated after the type hinted variable assignation.

Comment: @LouisSaglio But that's the case now

Comment: So why is the name of the dataclass-attribute ```Thing``` overriding the module-level definition of the class ```Thing```? Could you please expand on your explanation?

Comment: @EdPorteous Because there two object that refer to two different objects.